# Register-WMIEvent Applications And Services Logs (Wail2Ban)

Tags: windows, powershell

I have asked a related question [windows-server-wail2ban](https://serverfault.com/questions/822206/windows-server-wail2ban-and-folder-sharing-not-working-together-error-4625-no)

I am trying to use [Wail2Ban](https://github.com/glasnt/wail2ban) with Windows Server 2012. As stated in the question above the log does not seem to take the IP and thereforeWail2Ban is unable to ban hosts without this information. With a few changes I could then log the IP but could not access shared folder.

A commenter gave me the following link [Event 4625 no Source](https://serverfault.com/questions/683837/event-id-4625-without-source-ip/814632#814632), so it seems there is a secondary log file for failed RDP authentication and this event does have the IP. Therefore I can remove the change made and instead use this log whilst keeping access to shared folders.

The next issue I am having is that apparently it is not possible to use `Register-WMIEvent` with Application and Service Logs. I have howevre, found some posts that show a workaround for this.[Accessing Extended Logs](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/461221/accessing-extended-event-logs).

I have followed the above and added the relevant key for `Microsoft-Windows-RemoteDesktopServices-RdpCoreTS/Operational`, now when using `Get-EventLog -list` I see `Microsoft-Windows-RemoteDesktopServices-RdpCoreTS/Operational` included in the ouput which was not the case before making the registry change.

I have not really touched Windows/Powershell before I am more php, but I can grasp some concepts of the code. Looking at the wail2ban powershell code I see

```
$SinkName = "LoginAttempt"
$query = "SELECT * FROM __instanceCreationEvent WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_NTLogEvent' AND TargetInstance.EventCode= <> 4625"
```

I then see

```
Register-WMIEvent -Query $query -sourceidentifier $SinkName
do {
    $new_event = wait-event -sourceidentifier $SinkName
```

I am able to see the output in the powershell windows but I never see it find event 140 from the application and security logs.

Can anyone advise how I could utilise these logs with the current code or at least minimal modification. I have a feeling if I knew the `TargetInstance` and `-sourceidentifier` I may be able to crack this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems my issue most likely was I needed a reboot after the registry changes.

The vast majority of my question contains the steps necessary to get this working, however I have answered this question on my related question [windows-server-wail2ban](https://serverfault.com/questions/822206/windows-server-wail2ban-and-folder-sharing-not-working-together-error-4625-no/823378#823378):

> I now have this working with a few alterations.
>
> I have changed the NTLM settings back to default, this is not
>   necessary to do unless you have followed other articles and changed
>   these settings.
>
> A commenter pointed me in the direction of [Event ID 4625 Without
>   Source IP](https://serverfault.com/questions/683837/event-id-4625-without-source-ip/814632#814632). It seems in the extended logs the IP is logged, just
>   not in event 4625.
>
> I followed the following article [Accessing Extended Logs](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/461221/accessing-extended-event-logs) and
>   added the registry key for
>   `Microsoft-Windows-RemoteDesktopServices-RdpCoreTS/Operational`
>
> I then changed one line in the `wail2ban.ps1` file to allow these logs
>   to be used
>
> ```
> $EventTypes = "Application,Security,System,Microsoft-Windows-RemoteDesktopServices-RdpCoreTS/Operational"
> ```
>
> ## Event logs we allow to be processed
>
> I also had to change the wail2ban_config to add the log file also and
>   reference the event type id
>
> ```
> # Wail2ban Configuration
> [Events]
> #[Security]
> #4625=RDP Logins
> #[Application]
> #18456=MSSQL Logins
> [Microsoft-Windows-RemoteDesktopServices-RdpCoreTS/Operational]
> 140=RDP Logins
> [Whitelist]
> # Add your whitelist here, in the format `IP = Comment`
> # Supports plain IPs , e.g. `12.34.56.78  = My Machine` 
> # Also, ranges, e.g. `11.22.33.0/24 = My Company Range`
> ```
>
> Adding the
>   `[Microsoft-Windows-RemoteDesktopServices-RdpCoreTS/Operational]`
>   section being the important thing here.
>
> Once I had rebooted so the registry changes could take effect wail2ban
>   started to work as expected.
>
> I found `wbemtest` (put in run) to be useful here as you are able to
>   query the logs and check to see if
>   `Microsoft-Windows-RemoteDesktopServices-RdpCoreTS/Operational` is
>   part of `Win32_NTLogEvent`
>
> Whilst I do now have this working, I will be looking at the solution
>   proposed by @moteus as this looks like an interesting solution, that
>   would be easily moved and installed.